# How to receive multiple values using an intent

Tags: java, android

I have my main activity using the startActivityForResult method which calls an activity that i need to return two string values from. I have it working to return one, but even with all the tutorials and other questions on here i have read i cant seem to get it to return the two values. Below is my code.

here is where i start the second activity:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivityForResult(addM, 1);    
            }

        });
```

Here is the activity it starts, i need to return the text that is in the titleField(which works now) and the yearField

```
public class AddMovie extends Activity {

String movieTitle, movieYear;
EditText titleField, yearField;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_movie);

    titleField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
    yearField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearField);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveMovie);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.setData(Uri.parse(titleField.getText().toString()));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
            //data.setData(Uri.parse(yearField.getText().toString()));
            //setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();

        }
    });
}



}
```

Here is the method in my main class that receives results

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if(requestCode == request_Code)
            {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    tempTitle = data.getData().toString();
                    //tempYear =       data.getStringExtra("movieYear");
                    Toast.makeText(this, tempTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    dbAddMovie(tempTitle, tempYear);

                }
            }

        }
```

The code that is commented out was one attempt at making it receive multiple values, although they failed. Any help with this situation would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not build a HashMap where the values are stored and return that throuh the intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("title",titleField.getText().toString());
returnIntent.putExtra("year",yearField.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

And on your main activity, onActivityResult:

```
tempTitle = data.getStringExtra("title");
tempYear =  data.getStringExtra("year");
```

Answer (score 1):

use `data.putExtra("keys", data);` instead of `data.setData(.....)`
and get data like;

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
    String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able be put extras on your intent and get that data through an associated tag. This is how I'm doing it from an Activity's onCreate.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("your_tag", "the string you want to get");
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();
```

Then in the activity you want that data (the MainActivity or whatever you're calling it)....

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getExtras().getString("your_tag");
```

It may also be worth noting that you can Override the onNewIntent in your MainActivity to handle new Intents coming in, mine currently looks like...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class AddMovie extends Activity {

String movieTitle, movieYear;
EditText titleField, yearField;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_movie);

    titleField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
    yearField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearField);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveMovie);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("title_field", titleField.getText().toString);
            data.putExtra("year_field", yearField.getText().toString);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

And this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == request_Code)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                tempTitle = data.getStringExtra("title_field");
                tempYear = data.getStringExtra("year_field");

                Toast.makeText(this, tempTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                dbAddMovie(tempTitle, tempYear);

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `putExtra` method on your `Intent`:

```
data.putExtra("title", movieTitle);
data.putExtra("year", movieYear);
```

Then in the Activity that opens, you can get this data as follows:

```
String title, year;
Intent data = getIntent();
if (data != null) {
    title = data.getExtras().getString("title");
    year = data.getExtras().getString("year");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new intent and then add your two variables

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), asd8.as.hwapp.timemonday.class);
            i.putExtra("username",username);
            i.putExtra("password", password);

            startActivity(i);
```

And then retrieving the information in your new activity as so;

```
public void getInformation(){

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        username = extras.getString("username");
        password = extras.getString("password");
    }
}
```